# Azure IotHubTrigger function gets never triggered in the cloud

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azureportal

I tried to create a Azure IotHubTrigger function (C#) that gets triggered when a new message arrives in the IotHub. My problem is that the function works locally to receive messages but when it is deployed the function gets never triggered. The app settings are also set in the Portal. Is it possible that I am missing some configuration to make it work in the cloud? I also tried to delete the function and recreate it and to use typescript instead of C# but nothing worked.

Below is the code of the function:

```
    [FunctionName("IoTHubTest")]
    public void Run([IoTHubTrigger("IotHubName", Connection = "IotHubConnectionString")]EventData message, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");
    }
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=... ",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "IotHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb:...",
    "IotHubName": "iothub-..."
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing you can try is to make a new consumer group on the EventHub endpoint in IoT Hub and specifying that consumer group in your Function (in the binding). Otherwise you're using the $Default group everywhere, and messages won't be received.

Comment: Are you using the free tier of IoT Hub?

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer thank you I will try to create a new consumer group

Comment: @Skin Yes I am using the free tier

Comment: @MaxNocker, I had that problem with the free tier.  Microsoft confirmed for me that it's not perfect and I wasn't the only one that ever experienced that issue.  I moved to the first paid tier and it was then fine.  I then moved back to free when I realised that the "Invoke Direct Method" approach was all I needed.  :-)

Comment: Only adding a consumer group does not work when the function is deployed

Comment: The function is only working if I create it directly in the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

As per your information there is something which is missing during the deployment from local. Because it is working from local and also working when it is created from portal.

Follow the below steps to check the issue.

1. Check how the function is getting triggered.
2. Enable Application Insights for function.
3. Check for the logs in Application Insights when the function gets triggered.

With this we can find the root cause.

Also along with this, there are two reason for the function app not triggering after deployment.

1. Add the application settings under configuration in function app.
2. If there are any connections made to storage, you need to add CORS.
   Try these steps and check if it is working or not. Also do share the error message if it is not resolved by you.

Apart from all these troubleshooting steps you share the information to Azure community. Check this [GIT](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/618) Azure function QnA